# Access to raw data from Microsot band 2

Tags: microsoft-band

Im a student and i'm doing a research. I decided to use Microsoft band 2 for it. for that, i need to get the raw data from this wearsble device. 
is it possible to get the raw data?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called " Companion for Band". it allows to get raw data from the Microsoft Band.

Comment: check it here https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pimp.companionforband&hl=en_US

Answer (score 0):

Although The Microsoft Band SDK is [no longer available](https://developer.microsoftband.com/bandsdk), you can try to search for the library file on the Internet (I recommend you start with Github).

If you're developing for Android, then look for `microsoft-band-1.3.20307.2.jar` or `microsoft-band-1.3.20307.2.aar`.

Despite Microsoft Band 2 is discontinued, the developer manual is still [there](https://developer.microsoftband.com/Content/docs/Microsoft%20Band%20SDK.pdf).

Comment: The Microsoft Band SDK never provided an interface to read the raw (sensor log) data. There's no technical restriction to access that data, but the SDK doesn't offer it.

Comment: @IInspectable I agree, the only question is: how raw is raw? :) or in other words, what did the  author mean by raw data, and what data in particular? Indeed, the SDK doesn't offer the raw-raw data. In order to get it, one would need to "hack" the BLE protocol.